# Link not working in nav bar on this page but it works fine on other pages

Tags: html, css

The link in my nav bar is not working. The text shows up but I cannot click on it. It works on every other page but not on this page.

I have tried messing with the css but have had no luck as it still will not allow me to click on the link.

Here is my html.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">About</a></li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li><a href="resume.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Contact</a></li>
        <li>Links</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

here is my css:

```
body{
    background-image: url(images/city.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.box {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    margin: 3.8% auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: white;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
}
div.head{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}
a:visited{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you mean that, of the 5 links in your navbar, the 'Links' and 'Portfolio' text is not clickable for you, because upon testing it myself the other three are fine.

In such a case, this may be blindingly obvious, but those two list items have no anchor links..

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: sorry I realize I was not clear. I have not added in pages for the portfolio or links page but the contact page link is not working on my end

Comment: <div class = "container">
<iframe src="link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="box"></iframe>
</div>

Comment: Hmm.. I'm still not able to reproduce any issues with the contact page link even with that. If you can put up the relevant parts of your code on something like https://codesandbox.io in a state which reproduces the problem then I can take a closer look for you.